# "Transfer" or "carry over"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm confused about the word usage. If I want to say about the feelings, customer experience, or impressions, which is better to use: "transfer" or "carry over"? Are they interchangeable?
For example, "The impression they have will be transferred/carry over to the company"

Comment: Both could be correct, but probably one is better for the context. What's the context? Who is saying this to whom, and where?

Comment: This is for an article about brand perception

Comment: Please give at least the actual sentences before and after, and preferably the full paragraph. In the absence of fuller context, I would not be inclined to use either "transfer" or "carry over".